# react-form-hook persist values

Tags: react-hook-form, persist

I am using react-form-hook for a registration form and when I navigate to next screen and come back to the previous screen (registration form), previously entered information is getting cleared. Is there a way I could persist the info? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use set initial value when your view render. If you persist  your data then first set your data localStorage and when view rendered then initially set values into form those data